# Python Manipulating String

Tags: python, string, delimiter

I have a "raw" variable that store:

```
*rawVariable =* "Hello" "World"  "String 1"  "String 2"  "String 3"  "Sting 4"   
"Hello" "World"  "String 5"  "String 6"  "String 7"  "String 8"   
"Hello" "World" "String 9"  "String 10"  "String 11"  "String 12"
```

Is it possible that I store the word in a array with front and back double quotes as a delimiter?

I unable to use `"` as delimiter.

*Example:*

```
formattedArray = ["Hello","World","String 1","String 2","String
3","Sting 4","Hello","World"  "String 5","String 6","String 7","String
8","Hello","World","String 9","String 10","String 11","String 12"]
```

**Note:**

- There are different spacing (including `\n`) between the word.
- I will be storing into 2D array after the formattedArray.

Comment: What problems are you having? Your example code works fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What example code? I think he wants to for the array from his raw variable.

Comment: Please be more explicit about the format of *rawVariable*. Is it a string defined that way in a line of python (in which case it is just the individual substrings concatenated, and you will have to split on capital letters)? Or is that the actual string including quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question, but I'm guessing the following code might help you:

```
import re

def splitRawString(s):
    return map(lambda x: re.sub('^"?([^"]*)"?$', r'\1', x),
        re.split('"\s*"', s))

a='"Hello" "World" "String 1" "String 2" "String 3" "Sting 4" "Hello" "World" "String 5" "String 6" "String 7" "String 8" "Hello" "World" "String 9" "String 10" "String 11" "String 12"'
print splitRawString(a)
```

gives the following output:

```
['Hello', 'World', 'String 1', 'String 2', 'String 3', 'Sting 4', 'Hello', 'World', 'String 5', 'String 6', 'String 7', 'String 8', 'Hello', 'World', 'String 9', 'String 10', 'String 11', 'String 12']
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! Both answer did the same job (to a certain extent) but I prefer this because it is more solid.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you just need to split the string via `"` delimeter and get every other substring (since the interesting ones will be interwined with whitespace):

```
def split_quoted_strings(s):
    split_via_quote = s.split('"')
    return split_via_quote[1::2]
```

Testing appears to yield correct results:

```
>>> a='"Hello" "World" "String 1" "String 2" "String 3" "Sting 4" "Hello" "World" "String 5" "String 6" "String 7" "String 8" "Hello" "World" "String 9" "String 10" "String 11" "String 12"'
>>> split_quoted_string(a)
['Hello',
'World',
# omitted
'String 12']
```